# Lenovo Yoga 900 Internal Microphone Not Working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, microphone

The internal microphone suddenly stopped working in Ubuntu 18.04 on my Lenovo Yoga 900 laptop. It was working for a while before so I suspect some update caused it to stop working.

The internal microphone is detected, but simply picks up no sound ([note the input level in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26baw.png)). I have tried an external microphone and it successfully picks up sound.

My alsa info can be found [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=7ea445ced0d51944b933ab2dcf3449286a5bb741).

Comment: I have the same issue (Yoga 920, Ubuntu 17.10).

Comment: When I had a similar problem with a `snd_hda_intel` device... I found this page a good jumping-off point. https://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Help_To_Debug_Intel_HDA - although in the end, I did have to write a kernel patch to get it fixed.... the HDA codec graphing tool was a great start point. My problem was in the "patch panel" code - the stuff that determines which virtual "wires" are connected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with yoga 920 and ubuntu 18.04, the mic was working on 16.04 but stopped after the upgrade.

I'm not entirely sure how I managed to resolve it though.

Firstly I added `load-module module-echo-cancel` to the end of `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and restarted pulseaudio, for no reason really, simply wanted to check whether it would help or not. It didn't.

Then I booted into my windows partition and disabled Dolby through Lenovo Vantage, the on/off switch can be found in the hardware/audio tab.

After I booted back into ubuntu the mic started working. Although maybe the pulseaudio+reboot fixed the mic, and not the Dolby disabling. Later I enabled Dolby back and the mic was still working in ubuntu.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. Neither with nor without disabling Dolby on Windows.

I am on a Yoga C930 with Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: @RenéSteetskamp did you every figure this out? I've got the C940.