# How to fix internal microphone which stopped working on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.4 on a Lenovo Thinkpad T400. I have been using the microphone **in the past without problems** with applications such as Google Hangouts, Skype, ... - Recently, I tried to have a call and noticed that the microphone **stopped working**. Speakers are fine. I cannot tell how long the microphone misfunctions or if it stopped working with a software update or such.

## What I tried

1. I checked *System Settings / Sound / Input* - there is nothing muted and the input level does not recognize any sound.

   [image: System Settings]
2. I checked `alsamixer` but could not find anything unusual. Here a screenshot where the internal microphone is selected (last column, red).

   [image: alsamixer screenshot]
3. I checked `puvacontrol`. Nothing suspicious there.

   [image: puvacontrol]
4. I tried `sudo alsa force-reload` and the rebooting. No success.
5. I tried reinstalling `alsa-base` and `pulseaudio`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove alsa-base pulseaudio  
   sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio  
   sudo alsa force-reload
   ```

   Rebooting after. Microphone is still not working.
6. When I plug in an **external microphone** then the input level in *System Settings / Sound / Input* does **successfully** recognize the sound.
7. I let the pulse configuration to be created freshly:

   ```
   mv ~/.config/pulse/ ~/.config/pulse.BAK
   ```

   Rebooting after. Microphone is still not working.

## Question

What can I do to fix the microphone?
Please let me know if I can provide any information such as `alsa-info` to diagnose the issue.

## Related

- [Internal microphone not working on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149380/internal-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04)
- [Lenovo Yoga 900 Internal Microphone Not Working on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050244/lenovo-yoga-900-internal-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04)
- [Internal microphone not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6993/internal-microphone-not-working)
- [How To Fix No Sound in Ubuntu And Linux Mint](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/)

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem. All the orthodox solutions didn't help. I solved it by fiddling around.

Here's the witchcraft that worked for me:

1. Connect another external microphone and select it (sound should work)
2. Disconnect the microphone you want to get working
3. Reconnect the microphone you want to get working

Input sound should now work again for this microphone by the means of black magic.

Comment: A good example of "jank" versus "hack".  :-D